# Apache NetBeans IDE absolute path intellisense in a web project

Tags: html, css, netbeans

I have:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And I have the bootstrap file in the project, but Apache NetBeans IDE 18 is still showing errors for the underlying classes:

[image]

If I do:

```
<link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then NetBeans recognizes the path.

My Project Folder and Source Folder points to the same directory where all files reside. Web Root is set to `<Source Folder>`. What do I need to change to enable absolute path CSS to be recognized by Apache NetBeans IDE?

Comment: I just created a simple HTML project in NetBeans with a css file in **public_html**. Specifying the absolute path to that file as a URL in my HTML using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8383/HTML5Application/newcss.css" type="text/css"/>` worked fine (even though NetBeans incorrectly complained that underlying classes could not be found, as shown in your screen shot). But is there a specific reason that you want or need to use an absolute path?

Comment: @skomisa `/css/bootstrap.min.css` is the sanest way to do it. Adding `http://localhost:8383/` is redundant at best, and of course breaks your site when you deploy it, and you say it doesn't solve the problem anyway :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The path you cite as _"the sanest way to do it"_ is exactly the path that is giving the OP problems! The OP asked _"What do I need to change to enable absolute path CSS to be recognized by Apache NetBeans IDE?"_ and I provided a  solution which uses an absolute path that works in NetBeans. I tested it and it works, so your allegation that my approach _"doesn't solve the problem anyway"_ is false. And I specifically asked the OP for clarification on their motivation for wanting to use an absolute path because it is generally not a good idea.

Comment: My excuses if I misunderstood when you said "NetBeans incorrectly complained that underlying classes could not be found".

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález The problem is that the OP's path `/css/bootstrap.min.css` did not work, and their CSS file was not used at runtime. Associated with that problem, the OP pointed out that NetBeans was also showing errors (which are of the form _"Class {x} not found"_) in the HTML file. I changed the URL so that my CSS file was found at runtime. As a separate matter I pointed out that even for my absolute URL, which worked fine, _"NetBeans **incorrectly** complained that underlying classes could not be found"_. But I never stated that my URL _"doesn't solve the problem"_. The opposite is true.

Comment: @skomisa, I need this to check if any of the CSS selectors are broken (i.e., not available in the CSS files). This is awesome when you're constantly upgrading CSS, as I do. However, I have to use absolute paths because I'm duplicating my pages across the entire project, which includes a nested folder structure. As a result, I can't use relative paths